# How to format double result and return?

Tags: c#, formatting, return-value

I want to format result and return, how i can do that?

```
public virtual double GetArea()
{
    return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
}
```

Comment: How do you want it to be formatted?

Comment: And why would you want *this* piece of code to do the formatting? I'd argue that you should keep the formatting *well* away from the computation code. You may well need to format the same result two different ways in different user interfaces, for example.

Comment: Your method currently returns `double`, which has no formatting - it just represents the number itself. You will need to return `string` if you want it to be formatted as text, or convert the `double` to a `string` of your preferred format elsewhere.

Comment: "Format" in what way?  Currently this simply returns the resulting `double` value from the calculation.  What are you expecting it to return?

Comment: @JonathonChase two digits after coma

Comment: @Yamis: The `double` value has no "comma" or even "digits", it's just a numeric value.  Display formatting is done in the UI.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring

Comment: Do you want to round to two digits or truncate at two digits?

Comment: @JonathonChase i want have result as 24,85 but not 24,855646464

Comment: @Yamis: Then that would be "truncating", not rounding.

Comment: @JonathonChase that would round the result to 24.86

Comment: @AndréSanson Huh, I did not realize there was an implicit rounding to that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public virtual double GetArea()
{
    return Math.Round(Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius, 2);
}
```

`Math.Round` will round a integer to the number of decimal places specified in the second parameter - in this instance, it will round to two decimal places.

**Update, for reference;**

`Math.Floor` rounds down, `Math.Ceiling` rounds up, and `Math.Truncate` rounds towards zero. Thus, `Math.Truncate` is like `Math.Floor` for positive numbers, and like `Math.Ceiling` for negative numbers.

For completeness, `Math.Round` rounds to the nearest integer. If the number is exactly midway between two integers, then it rounds towards the even one.

Answer (score 1):

```
(Math.Truncate(GetArea() * 100) / 100).ToString("N2");
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post (like for example, what does "N2" mean), and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.